# paramiko - How can I refresh the modified date of a file on the SFTP server automatically?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, last-modified

I have a file on the SFTP server that should be imported with **paramiko** package on certain conditions. Until these conditions aren't fulfilled, this file should stay on the server unimported, but its modified date shoud be updated, so that this date should be always bigger than the time, at which file was checked by my import program.

I read the [documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/sftp.html) for the package but didn't found any function that could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [`utime` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.utime):

```
 utime(path, times)
```

> Set the access and modified times of the file specified by `path`. If `times` is `None`, then the file’s access and modified times are set to the current time. Otherwise, `times` must be a 2-tuple of numbers, of the form `(atime, mtime)`, which is used to set the access and modified times, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with copying the file from the SFTP to the local host, removing the file from the SFTP and copying it again to the SFTP.

So,

1. `get(remotepath, localpath, callback=None)`
2. `remove(path)`
3. `put(localpath, remotepath, callback=None, confirm=True)`

If anyone has another idea, please share your knowledge!

Comment: Not a good idea, I'm afraid. If your program, the server or network fails in the middle of the process, you may just kill the file or even truncate or corrupt its contents.

Comment: paramiko can open file for appending (see my answer). I'm almost sure that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try opening the file in append mode ("a") and closing it immediately.